# zfs releases space before destroying snapshots

Tags: zfs

I cleaned up today.

When I started my filesystem was 90% full. Now it is showing 87%:

```
Filesystem       1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
rpool/DATA     23201798016 20038152576 3163645440  87% /data
```

Now that would be very normal, except I have a zfs snapshot from last night and the data I removed was written before last night - thus I can access this data through a snapshot.

I had expected I would only get the storage freed after I had destroyed every snapshot that contained the removed data.

How can 3% get released when there are snapshots holding the data I removed?

Comment: Don't know, but maybe there was some dediluplication going on, triggered by the snapshot?

Comment: I thought dedup was only triggered by writes, not by snapshots?  Maybe there was another snapshot that was automatically released or some other files deleted or some pending deletions that finished?

Comment: I have not actively activated dedup. I will not rule out, that it was on by default, but I doubt it.

Comment: Can you share the result of `zfs list -ro space`